# Remote VPN connectivity - international - DNS geolocation

Tags: vpn, dns, cisco-anyconnect

I am setting up Anyconnect for multiple organizations with offices world wide. They are going to be sharing two Azure data centers which have vASAs, one is in Europe and the other is in the US. At each location we will have a hub and spoke topology to all sites for each organization.

We plan to use Anyconnect for remote access. I'm trying to sort out the most logical way to set this up considering that users will be coming from all over and will also be traveling internationally. Here are my thoughts, and questions:

Three main business groups biz1, biz2, and biz3. All of them will have resources in the Azure data centers and may need access to resources at specific sites

Option 1:
Have FQDNs vpn.biz1.com, vpn.biz2.com, and vpn.biz3.com. Point the DNS records to a site that "represents" each company. Get SSL certs each for these. Downside is that users needing access to the data centers will end up hairpinning (u-turn) out of the ASA at each site and go back into the data center. Using twice the data. If users are international then they may end up having high latency depending on which business they are with. Biz1 is mostly US, while Biz2 and Biz3 are mostly EU.

Option 2:
Use the Azure data centers as hubs for these connections. Most will end up needing access to the resources there anyway and if they do need access to resources that are local to sites, they will then hairpin out to the site they need to access.

Option 2 seems like it would make the most sense, but I don't know how we would should resolve the names. It would be fantastic if when a user for Biz1 is in the US, they will resolve the vpn.biz1.com address to the public IP for the US Azure site. And if they are in Europe they will get the other.

What options exist to geographically resolve addresses?

What issues could I experience with SSL certificates? Not my strong suit but I thought that SSL Certificates need to be bound to 1 domain name and 1 public IP. Can a single certificate be used for two separate public IP addresses?

All sites have ASAs.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Unfortunately, DNS is off-topic here because it is a protocol above OSI layer-4. IP addresses have nothing to relate them to geography. You may be able to engage a geo-location service, but that is off-topic here too. This question may be a better fit for [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 2 could be done with split DNS. Over [here](http://geoip.site/) you can download ready to use geolocation databases for BIND.

Option 3 you can build your VPN solution based on anycast.

Comment: Could either of these options work in a situation where the user is at any location? Say they are using the ISP's DNS server or the DNS server at a Starbucks (which probably relays out to the ISP's DNS)

Comment: Yes it should work just fine.